# filezilla: 'slice' transferring

Tags: data-transfer, file-transfer, filezilla

If I'm transferring a 2GB sql file with filezilla, and it timed out after 50%. 
In my server, I can see that the new transferred file is about 1.1GB.

I want to know if there's a way through the same method (filezilla : ftp/sftp), to transfer the remaining .9GB without re-transferring the whole file again?

Comment: Did you ask on the FileZilla forums? http://forum.filezilla-project.org/

Comment: what error code came up when the transfer timed out?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can drag the file over again, and then, when the dialog pops up to ask if you want to overwrite the existing file, select "Resume" instead.

*(I don't have FileZilla handy right now, so I'm going from memory here.)*